# Get the selected item from a spinner - MVVM - Databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I want to get data from the spinner using data binding MVVM, how can I do that please.

This is my spinner the data is loaded from an array list

```
    <data class=".AddProductBinding">
        <variable
            name="addProductViewModel"
            type="com.rao.iremind.AddProductViewModel" />
    </data>

  <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_catagory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:entries="@array/product_catagory"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_catagory" />
```

How can I get the selected item in my view model

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Spinner doesn't have binding adapters written for your use-case. So you have two options:

1. Create a simple `Binding Adapter` for your listener

```
 @BindingAdapter("onItemSelected")
 fun Spinner.setItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener: (T) -> Unit) {
        setOnItemClickListener{ _, view, _, _ ->
           itemSelectedListener(...)
    }
}
```

Then from databinding

```
app:onItemSelected="@{(value) -> addProductViewModel.onItemSelected(value))}" />
```

2. Set up an `Inverse Binding Adapter`, which you can check out in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)